# App's icon not visible in Phonegap Build's page

Tags: android, image, cordova, icons, phonegap-build

I have made an Android application. It was done by Phonegap Build. Now I want to share it.

But whenever I go to Phonegap Build's page of my app (https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1539142) it doesn't show my app's icon. Rather it shows the phonegap's icon. Now it is not possible to share an app in this way. Image attached for showing.

[image: My app's page]

I am talking about the icon just beside the name of app. What is the problem and a solution?

Comment: I am having same issue. Adding icon as mentioned in the accepted answer did not help. May be it is because there are some recent changes introduced in the config.xml as mentioned here - http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/ ?? I am not sure. But I do not see my app's icon on the build page. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to add this line to your `config.xml`:

```
<icon src="AppResources/icons/icon.png"/>
```

And make sure that the Icon file is in the same Directory.

Answer (score 0):

@Abeer, You need to add all the icons sizes. I know that because I did it before with Android. When I added iOS, I marked the size of each icon on the icon. That way I could tell the size of the icon displayed. So when I added iOS to my [Splash Screen Demo](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1362035/share), Phonegap build used the 180x180 icon for iOS instead of the Android. In your case, I think you just have to make sure you add all the icons sizes. This is [the reference](http://tekeye.biz/2013/android-icon-size) I used.

**Adendum - July 15, 2015** 
@Abeer,
Source: 
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test

All examples:
http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html

I did not use Eclipse or Android Studio either. I upload www. I use github.com, is same as www folder

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if you don't mind can I see the source code of your project? That would be helpful for me. And moreover I didn't user eclipse or android studio to make the app. I just uploaded the **www** folder to get it done.